# Python scipy.optimize.fsolve find the first intersection

Tags: python, scipy

Let's say I have `f(x) := x^2-10` which intersects twice with `g(x) = 0`. This is implemented like following.

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import pylab
import numpy

def function_a(x): # f(x)
    return x**2-10 

def function_b(x): # g(x)
    return 0

result = fsolve(lambda x: function_a(x)-function_b(x), 0)
x = numpy.linspace(-10,10,100)

pylab.plot(x , 
           [function_a(y) for y in x],
           x,
           [function_b(y) for y in x],
           result,
           function_a(result),
           'ro'
)
pylab.show()
```

The `scipy.optimize.fsolve` returns the second intersection. However I would like to know the first intersection at all times. How could I achieve this?

By first intersection, I mean the intersection with the lower `x` value.

Comment: Please read [ask]. We can only help you with code that we actually see. Also, did you try reading the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html)?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I have read the documentation. But could not find a way to solve my problem. + I have edited my question to include the code. Thank you

Comment: Hm, I can reproduce your issue and have looked at the other root finding algorithms, and none are appropriate for this type of function (brentq, etc), or return the same result as this one. Note that if you change your initial guess to -1, it captures the left root. Maybe it just stops at the first root it finds... Is it interesting to you to do this symbolically, or do you want to use fsolve to get all the root of other polynomials?

Comment: @K.CI  I guess im interested in doing this symbolically for speed. I am doing a simulation which need a lot finding intersections. The function I have lets say `f(x, parameters)`. The parameters is used to scale f(x) and will vary during the simulation. I guess I can set initial guess to -1

Comment: @K.CI Could you post your comment as answer please? It did solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Posting my comment as the answer as requested.)

Apparently, this function, and others in scipy optimize, only find *a* root, not necessarily all roots. If you set your guess to `-1`, it gives you the left root.

Also, perhaps consider `sympy` if you have well defined, known equations, as I believe it can be used find all the roots.